# SQL Server Profiler: Get stored procedure name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-profiler

I am running SQL Server Profiler (SQL Server 2008). Is there a way to see the name of the stored procedure that is executing? I am profiling `SP:Started` and `SP:Completed`. The TextData column hasn't been helpful as my stored procedures are encrypted so `TextData` displays "-- Encrypted text".

[image: Profiler Screenshot]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried adding column ObjectName? This should show stored procedure names. I haven't worked with encrypted procedures, but I'd be very surprised if the names are also encrypted ('cause how could you call the proc if you didn't know the name?)

Comment: Adding ObjectName works perfectly! Thank you. File > Properties > Events Selection tab > Show All Columns checkbox > check ObjectName next to SP:Started

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the stored procedure is encrypted, try searching for text containing 'WITH ENCRYPTION' in your db.

Additionally, perhaps there is a point in which there's too much data being passed into the sp where SSP will not display the text.

Comment: I know that the stored procedures are encrypted. Does that mean that the name is encrypted as well and I cannot see the name in the profiler? The goal I have is to find out which procedure is slow. I have stored procedures calling other stored procedures and I need to know which of the inner procedures is slow.